# (Indy) How to catch a Button click event before ConnectTimeout is reached

Tags: android, delphi, indy, delphi-10.1-berlin

I want to make a simple function that the user clicks on a On/Off button and makes an Indy TCP Client try to connect to an IP, but sometimes the connection takes too long (due to bad phone signal) and the user may tap once again the button to turn off. Indy catch this event (Button click) only when ConnectTimeout is reached or when the connection succeed. So I was thinking in put a low ConnectTimeout and make multiple tries to connect so I can catch the Button click without waiting too long, there is another way to catch a Button click event anytime when trying to connect? Thank you.

@Edit:
Well, I decided to make my first idea: multiple tries to connect with a low ConnectTimeout and count them until reach the desired ConnectTimeout, while in the mean time I can check the button press to turn off.

I tested using a phone with HSPA+ connection and a metal plate (to simulate bad signal) and apparently it work.

The simplified code ended up like this:

```
var
DisconnectedOnce: integer;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPClient1Disconnected(Sender: TObject);
begin 
if ButtonIniciar.Text = 'Stop' then
    begin
       try
          IdTCPClient1.Connect;
       except
          if DisconnectedOnce = 0 then
          begin
            DisconnectedOnce := 1; // Try only one more time to connect, in this case ConnectTimeout must be set by half the desired 
            Application.ProcessMessages;
            IdTCPClient1.OnDisconnected(IdTCPClient1);
          end else
          begin 
            ButtonIniciar.Text = 'Start';
          end;
       end;
    end;
end;
```

The is something bad or unsafe on this idea?

Comment: Put the TCP client in a worker thread. To interrupt connection attempt then call `Disconnect` from the main thread.

Comment: @Victoria keep in mind that disconnecting a socket in one thread is not guaranteed to abort a blocking socket operation already in progress in another thread. It works in Windows. Not sure about Android.